# Doubt in simple functional limit

Tags: real-analysis

So example 4.2.2 (ii) in [Abbot's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1493927116) asks to show that

$$
\operatorname{lim}_{x\rightarrow2} x^2 = 4.
$$

The explanation is clear to me up to the final point. I will rephrase here the followed process and at the end point out my doubt.

Let $\epsilon>0$, then we must find an $\delta>0$ s.t. if $|x-c|<\delta$, it follows that $|x^2-4|<\epsilon$. Thus we write

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
|x^2-4| = |x+2||x-2|.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

We can "squeeze" $|x-2|$ as much as we like but we need an upper bound for $|x+2|$. If $\delta=1$, then $|x+2|\leq5$. Thus, choose $\delta=\operatorname{min}\lbrace 1, \epsilon/5 \rbrace$. If $|x-2|<\delta$, then it follows that

$$
|x^2-4| < 5 \frac{\epsilon}{5}(!) = \epsilon
$$

Now two questions. As far as Abbot explains, $\delta$ depends on $\epsilon$. If for example it happens that $\delta=1$, then $\epsilon=5$ and this is the other way around, $\epsilon$ depends on $\delta$.

Second, why does he chooses $\epsilon/5$ as the good delta? This should only be the case if $\epsilon/5\leq1$, right?

Comment: Yes, therefore Abbot picks $\delta=\min(1,\varepsilon/5)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of saying that more easily is$$|x^2-4|{=|x+2|\cdot|x-2|\\=|x-2+4|\cdot|x-2|\\\le (|x-2|+|4|)\cdot|x-2|\\=|x-2|^2+4\cdot |x-2|}$$since both $|x-2|^2$ and $|x-2|$ are bounded, then so is $|x-2|^2+4\cdot |x-2|$.

Comment: This is by far the clearest way

Comment: Thank you. Hope it help enough!

Answer (score 1):

Abbot picks $\delta = \min(1, \epsilon /5)$ because if $|x-2| < \delta$ then the two inequalities hold:
$$|x-2| < 1 \quad \text{and} \quad |x-2|<\epsilon/5$$
This is the effect of picking the $\delta$ as the minimum of two values. It forces $\delta$ to be equal to the smaller of the two.

The first one implies $|x+2|<5$, and the second one implies $|x-2|<\epsilon/5$ and so:

$$|x^2 -4| = |x+2||x-2| < 5\frac{\epsilon}{5} = \epsilon $$

Comment: Ok, your comment that "then the two inequalities hold" really improves the text a lot.

Answer (score 1):

you've got that:
$\lim_{x\to 2}x^{2}=4$ by definition is:
let $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x-2|<\delta$ then $|x^2-4|<\epsilon$:

$|x^2-4|=|(x-2)(x+2)|=|x-2||x+2|$
then by hyphotesis $|x-2|<\delta_{1}$ then let $|x|-|2|\leq|x-2|<1$, then $|x|<3$:

$\Rightarrow|x-2||x+2|\leq|x-2|(|x|+|2|)<|x-2|(1+2+3)<\epsilon$

$\Rightarrow |x-2|<\frac{\epsilon}{5}$, then let $|x-2|<\operatorname{min}( 1,\frac{\epsilon}{5})$ .

Proof:

let  $|x−2|<\operatorname{min}(1,\frac{\epsilon}{5})$

$\Rightarrow|x-2||x+2|\leq|x-2|(|x|+|2|)<|x-2|5<\frac{\epsilon}{5}5=\epsilon$

I´m not sure of my english.

Answer (score 1):

What matters is that for any $\epsilon$, we can find a $\delta$ that fits.

For large $\epsilon$, this is not a problem because if you found a $\delta_0$ that fits for some $\epsilon_0$, the same $\delta_0$ will fit for all larger $\epsilon$.

No, the real issue is for smaller and smaller $\epsilon$ and this is why we sometimes say when $\epsilon$ *tends to zero*. As $\delta$ may not be zero (zero would always work !), we must make $\delta$ smaller and smaller as well, and this is what creates the dependency between $\epsilon$ and $\delta$.

If it is not possible to find a $\delta$ that fits, because the variation of the function remains large, there is no limit.